# How to draw mouse pointer in HTML5 Canvas after Scale, Rotate, Translate, etc.?

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, scale, translate

How to  draw mouse pointer in HTML5 Canvas after Scale, Rotate, Translate, etc.?

```
function drawImage() {
        clear();
        context.save();
        context.scale(currentScale, currentScale);
        context.rotate(currentAngle * Math.PI / 180);
        context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 

        // Here I should expect to draw mouse pointer after scale, rotate or translate.       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the inverse matrix and apply it to the mouse coordinates.

To get the current matrix you can use `ctx.currentTransform` if available but there is limited browser support ATM so you should check for support first.

It returns a [SVGMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGMatrix) object, or a [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) object depending on the browser and version with the latter being the new (soon to be) standard.

When you have the current transform you invert it (see documentation) and then multiply the mouse client coordinates with the inverse matrix to get the coordinates of the mouse in the current transform.

If the browser does not have support then things get somewhat more complicated as you have to maintain the transformation yourself. There are plenty of example of how to do this already on stackoverflow. Again once you have the matrix just invert and apply to mouse coordinates.